# How to draw rectangles on SVG on click event?

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

I am using `raphael js` in my application. Here I need to draw a small rectangle on a point of clicking in raphael paper. I need to connect these rectangle using a line. Can anyone make DEMO of this. I am adding sample DEMO. Please update this.

My DEMO.:
[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/yaLfdw2p/1/)

```
var paper = Raphael("editor", 635,500),
        canvas= document.getElementById('editor').style.backgroundColor='gray';
```

Now I need to draw samll rectangles on clicking raphael paper and joing them with a line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick; http://jsfiddle.net/9dsgcv1c/1/

```
var paper = Raphael("editor", 635,500),
canvas= document.getElementById('editor').style.backgroundColor='gray';

var offsetx = paper.canvas.offsetLeft;
var offsety = paper.canvas.offsetTop;

var prevRect = null;
var rWidth = 50;

paper.canvas.onmousedown = function(e) {
    var posX = e.pageX-offsetx;
    var posY = e.pageY-offsety;

    var rectX = posX - (rWidth/2)
    var rectY = posY - (rWidth/2)
    var c = paper.rect(rectX, rectY, rWidth, rWidth).attr({fill:"#fff"});

    if(prevRect) {
        var p = "M"+prevRect.x +" " +prevRect.y +"L"+posX+" "+posY
        var line = paper.path(p);
    }

    prevRect = {x: posX, y:posY};
}
```

-

```
<b>Click on CAMVAS to draw rectangle</b>
<div  id="editor"></div>
```